# MySQL Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value?

Tags: mysql, geoip

I have a GeoIP table in MySQL.
The IP ranges are defined with `BINARY(16)`.
When I look up the IP address with the query:

```
SELECT `countries_countryID` FROM `geoIP` WHERE INET_ATON("84.224.199.84") BETWEEN `geoIP`.`ipFrom` AND `geoIP`.`ipTo` LIMIT 1;
```

I get warning messages (20-30000), saying: `"Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '17498112\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'"`

The Table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `geoIP` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `geoIP` (
  `geoIPID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `IPFrom` BINARY(16) NOT NULL ,
  `IPTo` BINARY(16) NOT NULL ,
  `countries_countryID` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`geoIPID`) ,
  INDEX `fk_geoIP_countries1_idx` (`countries_countryID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `IPTo_INDEX` (`IPTo` ASC) ,
  INDEX `IPFrom_INDEX` (`IPFrom` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_geoIP_countries1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`countries_countryID` )
    REFERENCES `countries` (`countryID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The result is correct, the country code is returned correctly, but there are theese warning messages. What is wrong?

Comment: WHy use `binary` for IP addresses? For IPv6?

Comment: It uses less space and later I will implement IPv6 also, which requires BINARY(16).

Comment: Inet_aton returns an int, then you are using it between two binaries. Surprised it even works to be honest, I would have expected it to blow chunks. Looks like you need to do some casting of IPFrom and To

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be storing IPv6 and IPv4 in the same field then you should use VARBINARY(16) in the table definition instead of BINARY(16).    This will remove the warnings.

In MySQL BINARY fields  (much like CHAR fields) are fixed width and are right padded.  You can see the padding in the warning.   The comparison is between a DOUBLE (the IP) and 1/2 of the BINARY(16) with the right half truncated.  That's why you're getting the warnings.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html